# How can we define $\mathbb{R}^0$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I'm reading a paper which asks to consider some box B $\subset \mathbb{R}^{v-1}$, for all $v\geq 1$. So for example, if we let $v=2, $ we would have that B $\subset \mathbb{R}$, so B would just be some interval $I$. I'm wondering what the case would be for $v=1$. Then we would be considering some box $B \subset \mathbb{R}^0$. I'm not sure what to make of this. Would it be empty...or just a singular point?

I can link the paper if its helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For my purposes, $R^0={point}$ serves the best. I work in geometric measure theory.

Comment: For any two sets $A$ and $B,$ an element of the set $A^B$ is a function $B\xrightarrow{f}A.$ For example: an element of  $\mathbb{R}^2$  is a function $\{0,1\}=2\xrightarrow{f}\mathbb{R}$ determined by two unique real numbers $f(0), f(1),$ hence an ordered pair.  $B=\emptyset$ is a special case, because there is a unique function from the empty set to any other set, called the empty function. Hence $\mathbb{R}^0$ is a unique point as a set, and (most of the time) you can equip this set with a canonical structure (like group, vector space, topology, manifold etc, but not a field) as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb R^{v-1}$ is the set of all $v-1$-tuples of real numbers, i.e. all functions from
$\{1,2,\ldots, v-1\}$ to $\mathbb R$.  In the case $v=1$, that's all functions from the empty set to $\mathbb R$.  There is one function from the empty set to anything, namely a function that doesn't do anything.

I'd have to look closer at the paper you're referring to, to see what is done with $B$, but my guess is that the author didn't really bother much about the case $v=1$.  Either didn't think about it at all, or is leaving this up to the reader.

Comment: Here is the paper, i'm only concerned with the first 3 pages. https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0404114.pdf

Comment: OK, it looks to me like $\nu \ge 1$ is a typo: it should have been $\nu \ge 2$. The $\nu$-level correlation measure makes no sense for $\nu = 1$, and is never used for $\nu = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, I had a follow up question about correlation measures... how could we interpret v-level Correlation Measures for the Farey Sequence? Intuitively, I understand the Pair Correlation to be the normalized relative spacing between 2 unordered elements in the sequence ...but what would be the meaning of the 3-level or 4-level correlation measures of the Farey Sequence? I posted the question on this site I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me out. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3890862/understanding-correlation-measures

Answer (score 2):

For $n \in \mathbb N$ we can think $A^n$ as the set of all functions from $n = \{0,\dots,n-1\}$ to $A$. An element $f \in A^n$ can be denoted as $f = (f(0),\dots,f(n-1))$. Thus, $A^0$ only consist of the empty function $\varnothing \to A$, and then $A^0 = \{\varnothing\} = \{0\} = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The way I think of $\mathbb R^0$ is as a $0$-dimensional vector space, so it is a singleton $\{0\}$ consisting of the $0$ element.

Comment: $0$ is a $1$-tuple, not a $0$-tuple.